# Proving limits using only limit definitions

Tags: analysis, limits

I need to prove the following limit using only the limit definitions (no limit theorems) and I am a little confused. If someone could please try and explain how to do it, I would be really grateful!

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} =\infty$$

Comment: Your friend Bob gives you a large positive number, like 1000. You need to find a large number $x_0$ such that that $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} > 1000$ for any $x$ bigger than this large number $x_0$. You need to be able to do this for any number that Bob gives you (the $x_0$ will depend on the number Bob gives you).

Comment: If your problem is on the definition of limit in this particular case, just ask, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Gibbs yes it is and that's why I'm confused. I can get to the part that x/sqrt(x+1) < sqrt(x)/sqrt(2) but I am struggling to show that sqrt(x)/sqrt(2) is greater than alpha

Comment: I assume your $\alpha$ is my $M$. Then if you fix $X = 2M^2+1$ you get that $X = 2M^2 + 1 > 2M^2$, which is to say $X/2 > M^2$, that is $\sqrt{X}/\sqrt{2} > M$. If then $x > X$ observe that $\sqrt{x} > \sqrt{X}$, so $\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{2} > \sqrt{X}/\sqrt{2} > M$.

Comment: @Gibbs thank you for the extra detail! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That the limit of that function goes to $+\infty$ means, by definition, that for any $M > 0$ there exists $X > 0$ such that 
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} > M, \text{ when } x > X. $$
Can you solve the inequality finding such an $X$?

Answer (score 0):

For $M>0$ and $x>2M^{2}+1$, then $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}>\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+x}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}>M$.